# Production Mode - CSS/JS missing when reloading with CTRL + Shift + R

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, javascript, css, static-content

**Hello everyone,**

As the title suggests, I'm currently having some problems with a Magento 2 site, running in production mode, and it's static content / caching. The website loads just fine, but when I try to reload the page without caching enabled in the browser (Ctrl + shift + R or disabling cache in your browsers developer tools) it's no longer working as intended. CSS and javascript seems to be missing.

[image]

Here's the interesting part, though. If I go into the page's source code with caching disabled and click on one of the CSS links, it still shows the correctly loaded CSS.

[image]

I've attempted to find anyone with similar issues, but it seems pretty rare? It's a semi-large live website, so I've not attempted to clear any caches, reindex anything or deploy static content yet, as I'd rather not completly destroy the "live cached" site as well.

I mistakenly changed mode to production while already being in production mode - I think it might have happened after that, as it weren't a problem before.

**Edit:**

I also just noticed that the deployed version in the deployed_version.txt file doesn't match the ones in the links, both with or without cache enabled.

File is 1578925531, website is 1578561207.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: can u please check .htaccess file available in pub/static folder?

Comment: @NareshRupareliya It's there and available :-)